# Each div another rainbow color

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have an unknown count of div-elements (generated) and i would like to style each with own "rainbow" - background-color like:

[DivExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T02FL.png)

please help me ^^

Comment: Hi Christopher, welcome to SO. Like Yousaf hinted at, you need to show a bit more effort in your own research of the problem to expect more specific help. Which we'd be glad to give :-)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [mcve]. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: You might need to do this with JavaScript.

Comment: Do you want their background colors to be in a repeating pattern or do you want them randomised?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var testDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
      var testColors = ['purple', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red'];

      for (let i = 0; i < testDivs.length; i++) {
        testDivs[i].style.backgroundColor = testColors[i];
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width:50px; height:100px; float:left" class="test"></div>
    <div style="width:50px; height:100px; float:left" class="test"></div>
    <div style="width:50px; height:100px; float:left" class="test"></div>
    <div style="width:50px; height:100px; float:left" class="test"></div>
    <div style="width:50px; height:100px; float:left" class="test"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

1. Select your elements (this case I selected them with `querySelectorAll`).
2. Initialize an array with the colors you like (this case it's the `testColors` variable).
3. Loop through the selected elements and assign a color to each from the `testColors` array.

If you have unknown count of elements, then you can count them after you selected them, like: `testDivs.length` (this case it's 5), and then create as many color as the length of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can just style every block in html:

```css
.block{
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class = "block" style = "background-color: purple"></div>
<div class = "block" style = "background-color: lightblue"></div>
<div class = "block" style = "background-color: lightgreen"></div>
<div class = "block" style = "background-color: yellow"></div>
<div class = "block" style = "background-color: red"></div>
```

You can add as many blocks as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I seperate the problem in two problems:
First, you need to get a code which creates matching colours when you say a number of elements. To make this, I use a code which creates color codes from the wave length. With this, you can easily make a rainbow-looking site from several coloured divs. To do that, I use [this](http://scienceprimer.com/javascript-code-convert-light-wavelength-color) code and use `colorSpace[0]`.
But to get the matching colours, I need to calculate proper wave lengths. The visible light is 450nm to 700nm. The difference is 250nm. So if you had for example three element, the perfect colours would be 450nm + n*250nm/4, n is the colour (1 to three).
A proper Javascript code to do this is

```
function GetLengths(number) {
    var Lengths = [];
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        var Number = 450 + (i+1)*250/(number+1)
        Lengths.push(Number);
    }
    return Lengths;
}
```

The second problem is to make the div get these colours. This can be made with Javascript, too:

```
var Divs = document.getElementsByClassName("WithColor");
var Length = 100/Divs.length
for (i = 0; i < Divs.length; i++) { 
    Divs[i].style.width = Length+"%";
    Divs[i].style.background-color = "here a color";
}
```

Now we must connect the code that creates Wave lengths, the code that makes wave lengths into colour codes and the code that gives the colour codes to the divs:

```js
var Divs = document.getElementsByClassName("WithColor");
 var TheWaveLengths = GetLengths(Divs.length);
 
 var Length = 100/Divs.length
 for (i = 0; i < Divs.length; i++) {
        var ColorCode = wavelengthToColor(TheWaveLengths[i])[0];
  Divs[i].style.width = Length+"%";
  Divs[i].style.background = ColorCode;
 }
 
 
 function GetLengths(number) {
  var Lengths = [];
  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
   var Number = 450 + (i+1)*250/(number+1)
   Lengths.push(Number);
  }
  return Lengths;
 }
 
 function wavelengthToColor(wavelength) {
         var r,
             g,
             b,
             alpha,
             colorSpace,
             wl = wavelength,
             gamma = 1;
 
 
         if (wl >= 380 && wl < 440) {
             R = -1 * (wl - 440) / (440 - 380);
             G = 0;
             B = 1;
        } else if (wl >= 440 && wl < 490) {
            R = 0;
            G = (wl - 440) / (490 - 440);
            B = 1;  
         } else if (wl >= 490 && wl < 510) {
             R = 0;
             G = 1;
             B = -1 * (wl - 510) / (510 - 490);
         } else if (wl >= 510 && wl < 580) {
             R = (wl - 510) / (580 - 510);
             G = 1;
             B = 0;
         } else if (wl >= 580 && wl < 645) {
             R = 1;
             G = -1 * (wl - 645) / (645 - 580);
             B = 0.0;
         } else if (wl >= 645 && wl <= 780) {
             R = 1;
             G = 0;
             B = 0;
         } else {
             R = 0;
             G = 0;
             B = 0;
         }
 
         // intensty is lower at the edges of the visible spectrum.
         if (wl > 780 || wl < 380) {
             alpha = 0;
         } else if (wl > 700) {
             alpha = (780 - wl) / (780 - 700);
         } else if (wl < 420) {
             alpha = (wl - 380) / (420 - 380);
         } else {
             alpha = 1;
         }
 
         colorSpace = ["rgba(" + (R * 100) + "%," + (G * 100) + "%," + (B * 100) + "%, " + alpha + ")", R, G, B, alpha]
 
         // colorSpace is an array with 5 elements.
         // The first element is the complete code as a string.  
         // Use colorSpace[0] as is to display the desired color.  
         // use the last four elements alone or together to access each of the individual r, g, b and a channels.  
       
         return colorSpace;
       
     }
```

```css
.WithColor {
  height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="WithColor"></div>
<div class="WithColor"></div>
<div class="WithColor"></div>
<div class="WithColor"></div>
<div class="WithColor"></div>
```

The Codes automatically counts the number of divs, creates matching colours and adjust the lengths of the divs.
Here is a JSFiddle that shows how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/Korne127/8hvgqkn2/1

Answer (score 0):

This should make it pretty clear how do do what you're asking. Choose your own styles. (I'm not a designer.)

```
<html>
<head><style>   #container > div{ height: 40px; width: 200px; border: 3px solid gray; }</style></head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    const colorNames = ["darkOrchid", "blue", "limeGreen", "orange", "orangeRed"];  
    // Assuming all the divs are inside the same containing element
    const divNodeList = document.getElementById("container").children;
    for(let i = 0; i < divNodeList.length; i++){
      let div = divNodeList[i];
      let colorIndex = i % colorNames.length; // Modulo operator ("%") let us wrap around
      div.style.backgroundColor = colorNames[colorIndex];
    };
  </script>
  </html>
```

BTW, you can see it running by pasting into an html file. (Tested in Chrome on Windows.)

Comment: I changed the formatting to make the code sample more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This will select any div and create a rainbow pattern.

```js
const colors = ["#3d207f","#6399e7","#adce37","#fdcd38","#e87452"]

let currentColor = 0
document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(div => {
  div.style.backgroundColor = colors[currentColor]
  currentColor >= colors.length ? currentColor = 0 : currentColor++
})
```

```html
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
```